# Is there anything special about words such as "Tutti Frutti" or "holy moly"?

Tags: word-request

I have noticed a series of words that are similar in some way as I've been learning English. For example:

- Tutti Frutti
- holy moly
- nitty gritty
- teeny weeny
- walkie talkie

I'm sure I've seen other similar words but I can't remember them. As you can see, these are all made by combining two sounding similar words. Could you help to give more examples? Why does English have so many of these kinds of words? Is there any special about them?

Comment: I don't know if there's anything special about them, but they're called **Rhyming reduplications** which should help you find more examples.

Comment: For what it's worth, "tutti frutti" is not really English anyway; we got it from Italian.

Comment: I found this to be a really interesting article about reduplication: [Why We Say “Flip Flop” Instead of “Flop Flip”](https://www.rd.com/article/ablaut-reduplication/)

Comment: @ColleenV: IKR... that's what I've been researching for about 3 months.

Comment: Easy-peasy, lemon-squeezy. Wakey, wakey, eggs and bakey. Itsy-bitsy. Rinky-dinky. Rock'em sock 'em. Joe Schmoe. Kissy-wissy. Scooby-dooby-Doo.  Hi-fi. Wi-fi. Sci-fi. SyFy. Hubba-Bubba. Since I'm tired of brainstorming them, I'll give you favorite one last:  love glove.